# I can't pip install python sabyenc on raspbian linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I can't pip install sabyenc and I need it for sabNZB to work. I googled a lot with no help at all.

Python version 2.7
pip version 1.5

Reaspbian Jessie

Below are the tracebacks from the log file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip-build-oG_yk7/sabyenc/setup.py", line 56, in <module>
        """
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 320, in __init__
Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
self.finalize_options()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 386, in finalize_options
ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in require
items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 859, in resolve
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (appdirs 1.3.0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('appdirs>=1.4.0'))
```

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip-build-oG_yk7/sabyenc/setup.py", line 56, in <module>

    """

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup

_setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 320, in __init__

_Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__

self.finalize_options()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 386, in finalize_options

ep.require(installer=self.fetch_build_egg)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in require

items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 859, in resolve

raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (appdirs 1.3.0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('appdirs>=1.4.0'))

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oG_yk7/sabyenc
```

Exception information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in prepare_files
req_to_install.run_egg_info()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 326, in run_egg_info
command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 716, in call_subprocess
% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oG_yk7/sabyenc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem in Ubuntu. python-appdirs needs to be upgraded. If you have Ubunutu:

- `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/appdirs/python-appdirs_1.4.0-2_all.deb`
- `sudo dpkg -i python-appdirs_1.4.0-2_all.deb`